# how to stop printing the log details in command prompt in netbeans?

Tags: java, logging, netbeans

i log the messages in the log file using filehandler in xml format. log messages are stored successfully in the log file. but the log messages are still displaying in the netbeans command prompt.

how to stop displaying those log messages?

Answer (score 0):

Review Your logger configuration and disable ConsoleAppender (if using log4j)

Answer (score 0):

> **logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);**

made me to stop the default root handlers and stops the logging in the console.